# Error: E0505 : E0505: App definition

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Getting error when executing below command.

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config coordinator.properties -run
```

> Error: E0505 : E0505: App definition [hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/oozie-app/coordinator/] does not exist

any suggestions.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain exactly what you're trying to do as it's not entirely clear from the question, and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Comment: I am trying to execute shell script using coordinator job scheduling based on data availability. When I execute, getting the E505 exception.

Comment: Fixed by placing coordinator.xml, coordinator.properties and workflow.xm files in the /tmp/oozie-app/coordinator directory.

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it! If you want to post it as an answer to your own question, you can help anyone else who has this problem and comes across your question.

Answer (score 8):

Please check below property from job properties file-

```
oozie.wf.application.path
```

This should point to HDFS directory where you have `workflow.xml` and 
`coordinator.xml`

Note that if the path DOES exist but does not contain a `workflow.xml` or `coordinator.xml`, you will still receive the same, slightly misleading `App definition ... does not exist` error.

Answer (score 2):

First you put the `workflow.xml` in the given `oozie.wf.application.path` using `hadoop fs -put workflow-full-path to-oozie-wf-application-path` script,

later you run the oozie script like below said -

```
bin/oozie job --oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie/ -config /home/arif/applications/hadoop/oozie-4.3.0/apps/sqoop/job.properties -run
```

I have defined the `job.properties` file like this -

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:9001
queueName=default

value_dfs=1

examplesRoot=/user/oozie/sqoop
exampleRootDir=${examplesRoot}/oozie-moviesdb-sqoop

oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}${examplesRoot}/
```

hope it will helps anyone by coming on this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem in running the workflow. The name of my workflow was `wf-somename.xml` which was the culprit. I later changed the name to `workflow.xml` from `wf-somename.xml` and that has worked for me.